# iOS Apple maps bug user sometimes gets wrong location (should be in The Netherlands, shows UK map)

Tags: ios, apple-maps

We've been having a few problems with the Apple maps inside our running app. Some users are reporting (and showing with screenshots) wrong maps. When tracking their run we keep their coords in our database and show them with the apple map inside our app. For some reason only a few people have the incorrect map when viewing their run. When loading the cords in google maps the location is correct.

Does anyone have this problem as well? See attached file from one of our users which runs in The Netherlands but gets an UK map instead.

[image]